# R - Calculate the average if 2 values present, calculate the median if 3 values

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which each individual has 3 possible readings of systolic blood pressure (SBP) and 3 possible readings of diastolic blood pressure (DBP):

```
a = data.frame(
  ID = c(1:10),
  SBP1 = c(120, 121, 122, as.numeric(NA), 123, 124, 145, as.numeric(NA), 101, 110),
  SBP2 = c(134, 124, as.numeric(NA), as.numeric(NA), 102, 133, 123, as.numeric(NA), as.numeric(NA), 109),
  SBP3 = c(111, 123, as.numeric(NA), as.numeric(NA), as.numeric(NA), 133, 132, 111, 110, 123),
  DBP1 = c(89, 90, 87, as.numeric(NA), 65, 98, 80, as.numeric(NA), 66, 65),
  DBP2 = c(90, 92, as.numeric(NA), as.numeric(NA), 65, 78, 88, as.numeric(NA), as.numeric(NA), 91),
  DBP3 = c(91, 93, as.numeric(NA), as.numeric(NA), as.numeric(NA), 92, 78, 88, 88, 54)
)
```

I would like to create two new variables (one for the SBP called 'SBP_new', and the other for the DBP called 'DBP_new') using the following rules:

1. If all 3 of the SBP/DBP readings are complete, then calculate
   the median (e.g., for ID1, SBP_new = 120, DBP = 90)
2. If two of the 3 SBP/DBP readings are present, then calculate the
   mean (e.g., for ID5, SBP_new = (123+102)/2 and DBP_new = (65+65)/2)
3. If only 1 pair of SBP/DBP reading available, then take that pair
   (e.g., for ID3, SBP_new = 122, DBP_new = 87)
4. Finally, if all NA, then assign NA (e.g., for ID4, SBP_new = NA,
   DBP_new = NA)

I can subset my dataset into 4 subsets and then do the calculation in each individually then combine.

But is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: To simplify things, you can just use the median for all 4 conditions - the median of 2 values is the mean, the median of 1 value is the value, and the median of NA is NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@Ritchie Sacramento](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835261/ritchie-sacramento) says in his [comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72420710/r-calculate-the-average-if-2-values-present-calculate-the-median-if-3-values/72420961#comment127936756_72420710), compute the median for all cases. But remove `NA`'s depending on whether or not all values are `NA`.

```r
i_sbp <- grep("SBP", names(a))
i_dbp <- grep("DBP", names(a))

a$SBP_new <- apply(a[i_sbp], 1, \(x) median(x, na.rm = any(!is.na(x))))
a$DBP_new <- apply(a[i_dbp], 1, \(x) median(x, na.rm = any(!is.na(x))))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>